# Getting data in a sub-document

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[image][image]

Hello guys, can you help me with my problem? I need to show all the data in a `TextView` in the sub-document ("Time"). Help me I'm a noob.

```
db3.collection("Blood_Glucose").document(uid).collection("Date").document(date).collection("Time").document(time).set(answer);
```

Comment: Please add your database structure as a screenshot.

Comment: Please add some screenshot about your data structure so we can help.

Answer (score 1):

To get the data inside that document you have to make a `get()` call and attach a listener as in the following lines of code:

```
DocumentReference timeRef = db3.collection("Blood_Glucose").document(uid)
    .collection("Date").document(date)
    .collection("Time").document(time);
```

Assuming that:

```
uid = rom.reyes2398@yahoo.com
date = December 04, 2019
time = 03:15 AM
```

To get the value of `Result` for example, please use the following lines of code:

```
timeRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
            if (document.exists()) {
                String result = document.getString("Result");
                String date = document.getString("Date");
                String time = document.getString("Time");
                Log.d(TAG, result + " / " + date  + " / " + time);
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "No such document");
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "get failed with ", task.getException());
        }
    }
});
```

The result in your logcat will be:

```
Risk of Having HyperGlycemia / December 04, 2019 / 03:15 AM
```

Comment: and i need also to get the time and date bro

Comment: In that case, please see my updated answer. Does it work now?